# Complex Roots for $(z+1/z)^2 -(z+1/z) -1 =0$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\newcommand{\w}{\omega}$$
$$\newcommand{\cis}{\text{cis}}$$

Let $A=-1$.
Let
$\w_1,\w_2,\w_3,\w_4,\w_5$ be 5th roots of $A$.
Which of the roots are solutions to the equation
$(z+1/z)^2 -(z+1/z) -1 =0$?

With
$\w_1 = \cis(\pi/5)$,
$\w_2 = \cis(3\pi/5)$,
etc.

Comment: Basically, you have two options: either approach it as a multiple choice question and plug in each of the five given numbers into that equation to see which one(s) satisfy it, or solve the equation first and see which one(s) of its roots is/are among the given numbers. Can you share what you've tried already and/or any of your own thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i took it to heart and realised i can simply the equation with De Moivres and then sub in the values.

Answer (score 1):

As $z\ne0,$ on simplification

$$0=z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1=\dfrac{z^5-1}{z-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: complex roots of $z^5=-1$ satisfy

$$0 = (z+1)(z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1)= (z+1)\cdot z^2\left(\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)- \left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)+1\right)$$

Now try to express $z^2 + 1/z^2$ in terms of $z+1/z$.